# Custom Launchers and Choosers in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

Obviously, There are more module of features in my Windows Phone 8 app. Normally i will restrict the developer to communicate between module to module. Hence i prefer to use Launcher and Choosers to solve this big trouble. Obviously my custom Launcher/Chooser will have their own Show() method to call the particular module as like build in Chooser/Launcher Task.Show().

In above case i should know the important concepts to follow when i write my own Show() method. From my knowledge these is the very basic one which comes by default *NavigationHandling*. Anyone could you please assist me on this?. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't write custom launchers and choosers. You can use only those that come with operating systems.

However, if you want to communicate with other applications, you can do it directly using [App to App communication](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-044) or via file extensions. In the former case you are quite limited since you must know which application you will call and what parameters you will supply, while in the latter case you tell the OS which file you want to open. This will show you a screen with all applications that can open that file type.

Both methods are limited and it is a shame that we don't have better app2app sharing capability.