# Launchers for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am studying for launchers in wp8 and developing the sample for the same.

Here is the link I am reffering to .

http://www.kodyaz.com/windows-phone-8/LaunchUriAsync-to-launch-built-in-apps-from-windows-phone-app-code.aspx

I am able to open the launchers mentioned in this app.

But, The problem is,

I want to open Kids corner, NFC, Internet sharing and battery saver in the same way like the other utilities(Bluetooth, Location and wifi..) are getting launched?

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaunchUriAsync only for following URI scheme listing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: This answer can help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702445/custom-launchers-and-choosers-in-windows-phone

Comment: that means not available?

Comment: Have you seen the video? Did you check LaunchApp class? another example of using this class for open NFC:http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_launch_apps_available_in_the_store_using_NFC_LaunchApp_tag

Answer (score 0):

## # URI SCHEME_____________________   DESCRIPTION #

ms-battery _____________________    Launches the Usage tab of the Battery Saver app.

---

ms-wallet               _____________________   Launches Wallet app.

---

ms-settings-camera          _____________________   Launches the Photos + Camera Settings app.

---

ms-settings-networkprofileupdate    _____________________   Launches the Network Profile Update app.

---

ms-settings-nfctransactions     _____________________   Launches the NFC Settings app.1

---

ms-settings-notifications       _____________________   Launches the Notifications + ActionsSettings app.

---

ms-settings-proximity           _____________________   Launches the NFC Settings app.1

---

ms-settings-uicctoolkit         _____________________   Launches a SIM Applications related app.               UICC appears to stand for Universal Integrated Circuit Card.2

---

ms-settings-workplace           _____________________   Launches the Workplace Settings app.

---

*These were the ones I could find ...*
**source:** http://leonzandman.com/2014/04/28/new-and-undocumented-uri-schemes-for-windows-phone-8-1/